# How to deal with non-normality in MANOVA?

Tags: normality-assumption, assumptions, manova

The dependent variables (DV) have to be normally distributed. I have a problem because some of them aren't. I have one independent variable (IV), namely *type of education*. The DV's are *Externalizing problems*, *Internalizing problems*, *Self-image*, *Motivation*, *Neuroticism*, *Perseverance*, *Social anxiety*, *Visciousness* and *Dominance*.
The research question is: for which DV's do the levels of the IV differ.

I assessed univariate normality with Kolmogorov-Smirnov, and the tests indicated that *Perseverance* and *Social anxiety* are not normally distributed. 
I also ran multivariate analysis based on Mahalanobis distance in order to find multivariate outliers. There are none. There are, however, several univariate outliers.

I tried to transform the data but when I did it, I transformed both the levels of the IV so the Kolmorgorov-Smirnov test remained significant.

My question is whether I now need to take the *Perseverance* and *Social anxiety* out of the MANOVA and run a non-parametric test on it. If that is so, which one might be the most appopriate? And should I do something like Bonferroni correction because I conduct several analysis now?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: DVs do not have to be normally distributed (and almost never are), but for some tests it is helpful if the *residuals* do not depart too far from normality.  For this purpose it is best to *plot* residuals rather than conduct formal testing (such as KS), because the plots reveal much more and the tests tend to be *too* powerful.  So, just to be clear: are you referring to the actual DVs or to their residuals in your characterizations of normality (or lack thereof)?

Comment: I am referring to the actual DV's

Comment: Then your entire question is based on a misunderstanding.  Check the distributions of the *residuals,* not those of the DVs.

Comment: @ Whuber Maybe it's a strange thing to do but I did a K-S test on the standardized residuals. There were no significant results, indicating I met the assumption of normality!?

Comment: @whuber if the residuals were normal, wouldn't the dependent variable also have a normal distribution, given the independent observations?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. The dependent variable will be distributed according to a mixture of normals, where the mixing distribution applies to their means and is a linear transformation of the distribution of the independent variables.  (This is just a way of stating the regression model.) That distribution will be normal when the independent variables have a (multivariate) normal distribution but otherwise is unlikely to be normal.